# SQL: MAX(data) com resultados errados

Tags: mysql, sql

Boas malta, 
tenho um problema, ao procurar a data mais alta agrupando por id, obtenho valor errado no campo obs.

Query em uso:

```
SELECT a.n_func,a.id_sk, a.data, a.obs, b.maxdata, b.obs
FROM chklist a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT n_func, id_sk, MAX(data) maxdata, obs
    FROM chklist 
    GROUP BY id_sk, n_func
) b ON a.id_sk = b.id_sk AND a.n_func = b.n_func
where
a.n_func=123
group by a.id_sk, a.n_func
```

Obtenho as datas certas mas o campo obs deveria aparecer vazio.

```
+--------+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| n_func | id_sk    | data       | obs        | maxdata    | obs        |
+--------+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| 532619 |       11 | 2016-03-21 |            | 2016-09-08 |            |
| 532619 |       13 | 2012-10-08 | notfunc    | 2016-11-29 | notfunc    |
| 532619 |      152 | 2013-05-29 |            | 2016-09-01 |            |
| 532619 |      200 | 2015-06-09 |            | 2016-06-13 |            |
+--------+----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

tabela original:

```
+------------------+----------+--------+------------+------------+
| id_chklist       | id_sk    | n_func | data       | obs        |
+------------------+----------+--------+------------+------------+
|            10607 |       13 | 532619 | 2012-10-08 | notfunc    |
|           922723 |       13 | 532619 | 2013-05-29 |            |
|           922724 |      152 | 532619 | 2013-05-29 |            |
|           922875 |      152 | 532619 | 2013-07-16 |            |
|           924753 |      152 | 532619 | 2014-01-17 |            |
|           926760 |      152 | 532619 | 2014-08-21 |            |
|           928527 |      152 | 532619 | 2015-02-23 |            |
|           930059 |      200 | 532619 | 2015-06-09 |            |
|           930635 |      152 | 532619 | 2015-08-28 |            |
|           932124 |      200 | 532619 | 2015-12-15 |            |
|           936359 |       13 | 532619 | 2013-11-29 |            |
|           932955 |      152 | 532619 | 2016-03-01 |            |
|           933179 |       11 | 532619 | 2016-03-21 |            |
|           934392 |      200 | 532619 | 2016-06-13 |            |
|           935026 |      152 | 532619 | 2016-09-01 |            |
|           935197 |       11 | 532619 | 2016-09-08 |            |
|           936372 |       13 | 532619 | 2014-05-29 |            |
|           936382 |       13 | 532619 | 2014-11-29 |            |
|           936503 |       13 | 532619 | 2016-05-29 |            |
|           936504 |       13 | 532619 | 2016-11-29 |            |
+------------------+----------+--------+------------+------------+
```

Desde já agradecido pela ajuda.

Comment: Consegue colocar o script de criação e inserção das tabelas?

Comment: Não fui eu que criei a tabela, mas creio que seja assim:create table chklist (
id_chklist int(11),
id_sk int(11)  ,
n_func varchar(100),
data date,
obs varchar(100),
PRIMARY KEY (id_chklist ),
FOREIGN KEY (id_sk) REFERENCES Persons(id_sk)
 )

Comment: Em que FOREIGN KEY pode ser multi

Comment: eu adicionei uma resposta, veja se te atende

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O correto seria você fazer a validação com um `NOT EXISTS` trazendo apenas com o registro com a maior data da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT a.n_func,
       a.id_sk,
       a.data,
       a.obs
  FROM chklist a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT b.n_func,
                         b.id_sk,
                         b.data,
                         b.obs
                    FROM chklist b
                   WHERE b.id_sk = a.id_sk
                     AND b.n_func = a.n_func
                     AND b.data > a.data)
   AND a.n_func=123;
```

> [**Subqueries with EXISTS or NOT EXISTS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)
>
> If a subquery returns any rows at all, EXISTS subquery is TRUE, and NOT EXISTS subquery is FALSE

Ou em tradução livre:

> Se a subquery retornar qualquer linha, EXISTS será VERDADEIRO, e NOT EXISTS será FALSO

Comment: you Rock! só não compreendo.. b.data > a.data é o que define a data maior?

Comment: É. Na realidade eu estou verificando se não existe um registro com as mesmas chaves mas que tenha um data maior. Sobrando assim só o registro com data maior